# animatewithduration is not working in ios 8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiviewanimation

I am using following code for setting the frames of three labels with animation. It is working flawlessly in ios 7 but in ios 8 it seems like animation is not happening.

Please help me to get through this situation.

```
int total = avgAwake+avgLight+avgSound;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    CGRect newFrame = lblSound.frame;
    newFrame.size.width = (avgSound*250)/total;
    lblSound.frame   = newFrame;

    newFrame.size.width += (avgLight*250)/total;
    lblLight.frame   = newFrame;

    newFrame.size.width += (avgAwake*250)/total;
    lblAwake.frame   = newFrame;

}];
```

Comment: I assume this has to do with autolayout. The easiest way would be to switch to constraint based animation.
Make sure to create width constraint for the labels and change its constant instead of using the frame.

Comment: try to use `NSInteger total =..` or `float total` instead `int total`

Comment: @TimBodeit I have used autolayout also but it is still not working in ios 8.

Comment: Using constraints and calling layoutIfNeeded should do the job there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quite simular problem so I switched to autolayout.

For this solution you have to define the new constraints and after that force an update of the constraints. The animation does the layout change:

```
//define the new constrains for "theView" here
.....

[theView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    [theView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```